# Proof in sequent calculus

Tags: logic, proof-theory, sequent-calculus

Is it actually possible to prove this in sequent calculus?

> if $\Gamma \vdash \lnot A$ , then $\Gamma \vdash A ⊃ B$

where $\Gamma$ is a set of formulas and A and B are formulas.

Comment: What about models where B is false?

Comment: I think it doesn't depend on that. The point here is that if you have a set of formula from which you can derive both a fact and its  contradiction then you can derive any other fact from that set.

Answer (score 3):

Details will depend on the system in play. But you should be able e.g. to argue from  (i) $F \vdash \neg A$ to (ii) $F, A \vdash \bot$ to (iii) $F, A \vdash B$ to (iv) $F  \vdash A \to B$.

Comment: Hi Peter! Could you please specify which rule  did you use to move from 1 to 2? Because I don't have anything like that in the list of allowed rules.

Comment: For $(i)\Rightarrow (ii)$: you should be able to prove $$\neg A, A\vdash \bot$$ or even go directly to $$\neg A,A\vdash B. $$  From there, you can apply a cut to eliminate the $\neg A$.

Answer (score 3):

@MauroALLEGRANZA has given an answer that are valid in classical logic, but the result actually holds intuitionistically too.  This is just a simple, intuitionistically valid modification of his proof:

\begin{eqnarray}
A&\vdash& A \\
A,\neg A & \vdash  & \\
A, \neg A & \vdash & B \\
\neg A & \vdash & A\to B 
\end{eqnarray}

At this point, as in @Mauro's proof, you introduce $\Gamma\vdash \neg A$, and apply the cut rule.

---

**Note** I originally commented that @Peter Smith's answer was also classical, but on reflection, I see that his reasoning is intuitionistically valid (and is basically the same as what I have above). He does not use the Law of the Excluded Middle.

Answer (score 2):

I will use the **LK** system [see Gaisi Takeuti, *Proof Theory* (2nd ed - 1987), page 9-on] :

> $A \rightarrow A$ --- *Axiom*
>
> $\Gamma, A \rightarrow A$ --- by n *Weakening*-left
>
> $\Gamma , A \rightarrow A, B$ --- by *Weakening*-right
>
> $\Gamma \rightarrow A, A \supset B$ --- by $\supset$-right
>
> $\Gamma, \lnot A \rightarrow A \supset B$ --- by $\lnot$-left.

At this point, we introduce the *sequent* :

> $\Gamma \rightarrow \lnot A$

and then, by *Cut* (with cut-formula : $\lnot A$ ) :

> > $\Gamma \rightarrow A \supset B$.

Answer (score 0):

$(A \rightarrow B)$ is a logical consequence of $\lnot A$, so if your sequent calculus is [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness), it is certainly possible to find such a proof.